# Checking a command with \equal and then using that command for another command?

Tags: formatting, conditionals, counters, ifthenelse

I am trying to check the definition of a command (either arabic, roman, Roman, Alph etc.) and from this information change the formatting of section titles, while making use of the command definition in the formatting commands.

The problem I am having is that I don't seem able to use `\ifthenelse` to check if two things are equal if there is a backslash present in the equality. However, going down another route, I can't use a backslash before the command to produce a new command since two backslashes yield a linebreak (this is shown in the example below).

Note that changing `\\sectionnumstyle` to `\arabic` in the first instance and then to `\Alph` in the second instance in the `\titleformat` command will produce a desired output.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper]{book}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[calcwidth]{titlesec}

\newcommand\sectionnumstyle{arabic}

\titleformat{\section}[frame]
    {\centering\Large}
    {Section \ifthenelse{\equal{\sectionnumstyle}{arabic}}
        {\oldstylenums{\\sectionnumstyle{section}}}
        {\\sectionnumstyle{section}}}
    {1em}{\centering}[]

\begin{document}
\section{Hello}

\renewcommand\sectionnumstyle{Alph}

\section{Goodbye}
\end{document}
```

I understand that I could simply use `\ifthenelse`, checking each possible value (arabic, roman, Roman, Alph etc.) and produce an outcome of `\oldstylenums\arabic{section}`, `\roman{section}`, `\Roman{section}`, `\Alph{section}` etc. based on each individual possible definition of the command however this seems long and unnecessary. If anyone has a simpler and faster solution it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to learn about `\csname...\endcsname`.  For example, `\csname\sectionnumstyle\endcsname` accomplishes what I think you were trying to accomplish, unsuccessfully, with `\\sectionnumstyle`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper]{book}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[calcwidth]{titlesec}

\newcommand\sectionnumstyle{arabic}

\titleformat{\section}[frame]
    {\centering\Large}
    {Section \ifthenelse{\equal{\sectionnumstyle}{arabic}}
        {\oldstylenums{\csname\sectionnumstyle\endcsname{section}}}
        {\csname\sectionnumstyle\endcsname{section}}}
    {1em}{\centering}[]

\begin{document}
\section{Hello}

\renewcommand\sectionnumstyle{Alph}

\section{Goodbye}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're a beautiful man